# Recuperación de contraseña

Tags: php

Estoy programando una página web y estoy en la parte de la recuperación de contraseña. La misma funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Tenemos que ingresar el mail y el número de documento de la persona.
- Ahí vamos a buscar los datos a la base de datos:

  - Si son correctos envía el mail con la contraseña que posee el usuario.
  - De lo contrario mostraría un mensaje de error.

La cuestión es que en mi código siempre me devuelve `false`, por más que ponga bien el email y documento que tengo almacenado en mi base de datos.

Estoy programando en PHP y estoy usando como servidor de bases de datos SQL Sever 2012.

Este es el código:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'conexion.php';

$email = $_POST ['email'];
$dni = $_POST ['dni'];

$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM WHAL.MDirecciones WHERE email = :E_Mail AND dni = :Nro_Documento");
    $sql ->execute(array(
      ':E_Mail'=>$email,
       ':Nro_Documento'=>$dni,
   ));

$resultado = $sql ->fetch();


if ($resultado == true){
      $mail->setFrom('aca va el mail', 'nombre del emisor');
      $mail->addAddress($email, '');
      $mail->Subject = 'Mensaje de Prueba';
      $mail->Body = 'Esto es un mensajito de prueba, saludos.';

      /* SMTP parameters. */
      $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
      /* Tells PHPMailer to use SMTP. */
      $mail->isSMTP();

      /* SMTP server address. */
      $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

      /* Use SMTP authentication. */
      $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

      /* Set the encryption system. */
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

      /* SMTP authentication username. */
      $mail->Username = 'mail del que envia';

      /* SMTP authentication password. */
      $mail->Password = 'password del que envia';

      /* Set the SMTP port. */
      $mail->Port = 465;

      /* Finally send the mail. */
      $mail->send();
      echo 'Mensaje se envio correctamente';
      header('location:../index.php?envio=1');
   }else {
      echo "Devuelve False.";
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: y si probas con `if(isset($resultado) || !empty($resultado))` ?

Comment: ¿Se te ha ocurrido comprobar la salida del `execute()` antes de hacer el `fetch()`? Es probable que haya fallado la consulta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia cuando ejecuto esa consulta en la base de datos (con las variables que ingreso en la pagina) me devuelve de lo mas bien el resultado.
Ahora si yo hago un echo $resultado, no devuelve nada.

Comment: Hola @ElioFarac y bienvenido a la comunidad. No me refiero a eso. Tal y como puedes ver en la documentación, [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdo-statement.execute) devuelve un `true` o `false` indicando si la consulta se ejecutó correctamente o no. Es probable que haya fallado por algún motivo. ¿Podrías comprobar el valor de retorno con un `var_dump($sql->execute( ... ))`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login2\php\sendmail.php on line 52
bool(false)

Comment: ¿Este es tu código exacto? Se queja de que tu `array(..)`  está siendo interpretado como cadena de caracteres. ¿Podrías comprobar la coincidencia del número de línea?

Comment: ¿Puedes probar a realizar la consulta de otra manera? En vez de: `$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM WHAL.MDirecciones WHERE email = :E_Mail AND dni = :Nro_Documento");` Prueba en los condicionales a meterle el POST que recoges de email y dni: `$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM WHAL.MDirecciones WHERE email = ".$email." AND dni = ".$dni."");`

Comment: @Juanjo .. por favor, no recomiendes realizar malas prácticas ni tan siquiera para hacer una prueba. El código debe funcionar correctamente haciendo una consulta preparada. Si no, puedes recomendar hacer uso de tu código agregando [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/pdo.quote) a cada variable.

Comment: Buenos días @ElioFarac . ¿Podrías contestar la pregunta que te hice? ¿Has conseguido arreglarlo o sigues con el problema? Gracias y que tengas un buen día.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Perdón, estuve probando ayer y nada, sigo con el mismo problema

Comment: ¿Pero podrías al menos responder las preguntas que te hice? Las repito: ¿Este es tu código exacto? Se queja de que tu `array(..)` está siendo interpretado como cadena de caracteres. ¿Podrías comprobar la coincidencia del número de línea? Estoy empezando a temer que pusiste tres puntos suspensivos tomando literalmente la línea `var_dump($sql->execute( ... ))`.

Comment: Si @OscarGarcia ese es mi código exacto. Y no, no puse los tres puntos suspensivos, dentro de esa linea puse la consulta que estaba haciendo en mi base de datos

Comment: ¿Habría alguna forma de ponernos en contacto en tiempo real? Creo que no tienes reputación suficiente para usar en chat de stackoverflow.

Comment: Una última sugerencia. ¿Podrías hacer un `var_export($resultado);` antes del `if` para comprobar su valor y cambiar la condición el `$resultado == true` por `$resultado !== false`? Piensa que en esa condición estás forzando una conversión de tipos y podría llevarte a error.

Comment: @OscarGarcia en estos momento no puedo, pero con mucho gusto cuando me desocupe entrare

Comment: Buen día @OscarGarcia , te comento que ya pude solucionarlo! Agradezco la disposición que tuviste con mi problema. Muchas gracias!
 Lo que me traía problema era esa consulta que estaba haciendo. Las variables que le estaba pasando estaban al revés, era  "WHERE E_Mail = :email AND Nro_Documento = :dni" y tuve que poner toda la ruta que hacia para ir a la base de datos.

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! Si hubieras capturado el problema comprobando las salidas de los `prepare` y `execute` hubieras podido ver el mensaje de error indicándote eso :) deberías acostumbrarte a blindar mejor tu código frente a cualquier eventualidad.